# Verb tense confusion - how to correctly use past perfect in a past tense narrative

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, simple-past, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

Okay, scenario: In a novel set in narrative past tense, there's a sentence, "We had become friends when nobody had liked him and it had seemed no one ever would." Is the past perfect being used correctly? Is "when" perhaps too ambiguous and unhelpful?

To my mind, there are three different times here: 1. the "now"; 2. the moment the boy and girl became friends; 3. the time when the boy had no friends. Put like that, the solution seems simple--use past perfect for the time when the boy had no friends because it occurred before the moment he and the girl became friends. E.g. "We became friends when nobody had liked him and it had seemed no one ever would."

However, because the novel is already set in past tense, I'm afraid using past simple for the moment they became friends, which is in the novel's past, would get confused with the "now," which is also written in past simple. So is it more appropriate to use past perfect for both past events, even though they didn't occur at the same time?

In that case, are all three hads necessary, or can it be used with only the initial verb (became) then understood to also apply to the two others (liked, seemed)? E.g. "We had become friends when nobody liked him and it seemed no one ever would." I swear I see that in novels *all the time*, but I can't find any sources to confirm it's a thing. Maybe that's a misconception on my part. Or maybe it's just super common to misuse past perfect.

Help :(

Comment: One *had* per sentence is plenty: "We became friends when nobody had liked him and **it seemed** no one ever would." At the time of becoming friends and not just before that, that is when it appeared that nobody like him.

Comment: I'd rather get the perfect form out of the way early: *We **had become** friends when nobody **liked** him and it **seemed** no one ever would.* If indeed there's any reason to use a perfect form *at all*, which for this specific example seems unnecessary unless some additional context justifies it.

Comment: I agree with FumbleFingers. I see no reason for the past perfect anywhere in that sentence. Can you quote or summarise what comes before it?

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers in that there may not be a reason at all for the perfect tense. "*We became friends when nobody liked him and it seemed no one ever would*" strikes me as more concise without losing any meaning.

Comment: Past perfect is required, yes, because as I said, the narrative tense is already simple past, so anything that occurred in the past of the novel, such as the moment they became friends, needs to be in past perfect. Or at least those are the rules of grammar as I understand them. What I don't know is if the verbs in the subordinate clause (liked, seemed) need to also be in past perfect, or if the fact that the clause was a time before they even became friends changes how the tenses are handled altogether. I know it's confusing, I'm explaining as best I can.

Comment: I'm not sure how more context would make a difference, but this is the entire paragraph: "They didn’t even know him: Nick, who felt anguish when watching spring, who was a musical prodigy, who had had my back for years. We had become friends when nobody had liked him and it had seemed no one ever would. Now he had a fan club and appeared to delight in his plentiful options; maybe that was why we were drifting apart. Toxic jealousy was added to the dark concoction inside me."

Comment: Thanks. In the context you quote, the past perfect is justified in the main clause and probably also the better choice in the subordinate clauses. As a general point, it is often useful to include the exact context, since simply explaining it may lead to misunderstandings as evidenced in the comments above.

Comment: This cannot be answered without a bit of context to the story that is necessary to interpret the meaning of the conjunction, which can have different readings (cp. *while* "because"). The problem is, English has no strict rule on focus and theme structure (and I don't have a good understanding of the theory, so take that with a pinch). Do we already know you had become friends? Does the isolation continue (do you want to foreshadow)? In other words, I think the criticizm from the other commentators is not warranted. Your verbiage is fine. Anything else is stylistics bike shedding. I Am ESL tho

Comment: Just **remember this**: It depends **on what you want to say** but in any case, a past perfect has to be preceded by a simple past. I came into the room when he arrived. I had come into the room when he arrived. Can you feel the difference?? People always complicate the past perfect when in fact it is rather easy=peasy. See Josef Baskin above.

Answer (score 0):

> We had become friends when nobody had liked him and it had seemed no one ever would.

There is a simple answer to your question.

Time, though is a tricky thing.  It seems this novel has a narrator as one of its characters.  So you are dealing with the following times.

1. The time at which the narrator is telling the story.
2. The time(s) in which the story or the events described  is set.

The narrative (2) is in the narrator's past.  So the dominant tense will be the simple past.  But the time at which the two became friends was before that: So it is doubly in the past; and the tense for that is the pluperfect ('had become friends') as in the quoted passage.

But **at the time when** these two were not yet friends nobody 'liked' them.  You might get away with the pluperfect, as in the passage, but strictly the continuous past is what is needed.

Similarly, strictly, 'seemed' is preferable to 'had seemed'.

Answer (score 0):

In narrative, the past perfect is used to provide background and context to what follows. What follows is usually the main point/event/idea. What follows is in the simple past.

The past perfect provides context and background by referring to actions or states that have been completed.

> *I **had dug** the garden and **washed**[past participle] my car*, so I was [simple past] hungry.

You will note that the italicised part simply gives background and context to your being hungry. Your being hungry is the main idea.

Your example is

> We had become friends when nobody had liked him and it had seemed no one ever would.

This is pure context and background. I expect it to be followed by

> However, things **turned out** to be quite different.

Simple past.